# How to translate in English a mythical phrase from an Italian film

Tags: translation, idioms, english-comparison

In a scene from *'Il Marchese del Grillo'*, *Alberto Sordi* explains to the villain:

> "Perché io so' io e tu non sei un c...o",

I have removed the vulgar part but I am pretty sure that every one understand. Today I was trying to explain to a dude on StackOverflow why Microsoft can break its own rules while we cannot. And this famous phrase has come to my mind. However the better outcome from my poor English was:

> "Because they are who they are and you are a none".

However it seems to me that a lot of the meaning is lost in translation. Is there something better to express the figurative power of the original expression? Well, of course, I have reconsidered to post something like that but nevertheless I wish to know if there is a better translation.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I'm afraid your question is off-topic here: this site it's about Italian, not about English language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can translate this marvellous quote from the movie with:

> *Because I am me and you're .... (nothing)*

without the use of the contraction on *I'm*, so when you read it you can give the correct tone to the sentence.

So similarly you can say:

> *Because they are them (or Microsoft) and you are ... (nothing)*

Comment: Because they are them and you worth nothing

Comment: Besides the fact that the question is heavily off-topic here, do you really believe that “nothing” has the same strength and effectiveness as Italian (or Roman) *un cazzo*? At the very least, but an English mother tongue is needed here, something like “you're fucking nothing”. (By the way, [there is no need to censor swear words](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-to-handle-swear-words), if it is to mention rather than actually use them.)

Comment: I think you're right, my aim, as the one of many others is just to help.....

Comment: Indeed, as is mine. Here I'm trying to help you. :-)

Comment: Good point. You didn't hurt my feelings at all